# Apache Ignite NoSuchMethodError using WebFlux

Tags: spring-webflux, ignite

Having problems initializing WebClient in Apache Ignite client node.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.codec.support.DefaultClientCodecConfigurer]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.xml.StaxUtils.createDefensiveInputFactory()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:4.3.26.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:102) ~[spring-beans-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:4.3.26.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.CodecConfigurerFactory.create(CodecConfigurerFactory.java:72) ~[listener-service-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.ClientCodecConfigurer.create(ClientCodecConfigurer.java:77) ~[listener-service-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultExchangeStrategiesBuilder.<init>(DefaultExchangeStrategiesBuilder.java:50) ~[listener-service-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultExchangeStrategiesBuilder.<clinit>(DefaultExchangeStrategiesBuilder.java:40) ~[listener-service-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.xml.StaxUtils.createDefensiveInputFactory()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;
        at org.springframework.http.codec.xml.Jaxb2XmlDecoder.<clinit>(Jaxb2XmlDecoder.java:83) ~[listener-service-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.support.BaseDefaultCodecs.initObjectReaders(BaseDefaultCodecs.java:503) ~[listener-service-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.support.BaseDefaultCodecs.initReaders(BaseDefaultCodecs.java:178) ~[listener-service-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.support.BaseDefaultCodecs.<init>(BaseDefaultCodecs.java:168) ~[listener-service-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.support.ClientDefaultCodecsImpl.<init>(ClientDefaultCodecsImpl.java:52) ~[listener-service-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.support.DefaultClientCodecConfigurer.<init>(DefaultClientCodecConfigurer.java:35) ~[listener-service-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:4.3.26.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:102) ~[spring-beans-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar:4.3.26.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.CodecConfigurerFactory.create(CodecConfigurerFactory.java:72) ~[listener-service-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.ClientCodecConfigurer.create(ClientCodecConfigurer.java:77) ~[listener-service-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultExchangeStrategiesBuilder.<init>(DefaultExchangeStrategiesBuilder.java:50) ~[listener-service-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultExchangeStrategiesBuilder.<clinit>(DefaultExchangeStrategiesBuilder.java:40) ~[listener-service-1.3.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar:?]
        ... 12 more
```

Simple webclient initialization:

```
webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();
```

It seems like reason is Spring-webflux and Ignite have different Spring versions (4 and 5). Also, it can be reproduced only at Linux environment.

Comment: Maybe you use JDK > 8 so you need to add explicitly jaxb dependencies in maven / gradle.

Comment: My openjdk version "1.8.0_332"

Comment: Maybe classloader is little different between linux and windows, so I have 2 jars with same classes, so you need to exclude some dependencies from Ignite or Spring...